# iCloud missing in settings iOS 10.3

Tags: icloud, settings, ios

After installing iOS 10.3 last night, iCloud is missing in my settings.

Can anyone help or advise ?

Comment: It should be there, I can see it on my iPhone.  Posting screenshots of your Settings screens will help us troubleshoot

Answer (score 14):

Starting with iOS 10.3, the **Settings** app features a section dedicated to your personal profile at the very top. You’ll find the old **iCloud** submenu in there.

Screenshot courtesy of [MacRumors](http://www.macrumors.com/2017/01/24/whats-new-in-ios-10-3):

[image: iOS 10.3 Settings]

Comment: Thanks. This is the second dumbest thing I've ever had to Google, behind how to shuffle my music in iOS 8.